# How to check which 1 is the oldest object or price?

Tags: mql4

[image]

On the picture above, blue horizontal line object is the oldest object, how to get it?

something like :

```
if (blue < yellow) &&  (blue < pink) &&  (blue < red)) { printf ("blue is the oldest object"); }
```

Do I need to use ibarshift? May I have example of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string oldestObjectName="", name;
datetime oldestObjectDate=INT_MAX, tmpDate;
for(int i=ObjectsTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
   name=ObjectName(i);
   tmpDate=ObjectGetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_TIME1);
   if(tmpDate<oldestObjectDate)
   {
      oldestObjectDate=tmpDate;
      oldestObjectName=name;
   }
}
printf("oldest object is %s, its time1=%s",oldestObjectName,TimeToString(oldestObjectDate));
```

Comment: You are very helpful, thank you. Now I learned using for loop get object name from new to old object 1 by 1. Thank you.